# Create and write to file a data from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, file

I would like to know, how can I write to file a data from JavaScript. I have a HTML with two buttons and in JavaScript I count the time between clicking of them. And I need variable "difference" write and save to a file to PC. I have not got server. How could I do that? Thanks

JavaScript

```
function startButton() {
startTime = Date.now(); }

function stopButton() {
if (startTime) {
    var endTime = Date.now();
    difference = endTime - startTime;
    alert('Reaction time: ' + difference + ' ms');
    startTime = null;
} else 
    alert('Click the Start button first'); }
```

Comment: Take a look to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: Create and save file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file)

Comment: Thanks, but I have 5 html files with start and end buttons. That's experiment with tasks and I need to get time how long the participant makes this task. All these times (from all HTMLs) I need to write to one file. It should be automatically without a participant's actitvity to download.